# decimal to binary conversion java

Tags: java

My method seems to only work for all int less than 2^10. If it is greater than or equal to this value then it just returns 2^32. I'm not sure how my program is even getting this. I need to make it work for all int less than or equal to 2^15. Can anybody at least see why it's returning 2^32 for int greater than or equal to 2^10? If so then let me know please.

```
public static int DecToBin(int num) {
    int binNum = 0;
    int divisor = num;
    int mod = 0;
    int exp =0;

    while(divisor != 0){
        mod = divisor%2;
        divisor = divisor/2;
        if(mod==1){
            binNum = (int) (binNum + (Math.pow(10, exp)));
        }
        exp++;
    }
    return binNum;
```

}

Comment: you can't, not this way. you are trying to represent numbers that are too large. You represent 2^10 as a 10^10 number, which is > 2^32. Use a String?

Comment: My method has to return an int type. I thought int was good upto 2^32.

Comment: Never mind I've been a fool. You're absolutely correct. I need string. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

An always easy way to accomplish this is:

```
Integer.toBinaryString(int);
```

This is the easiest way to do this but their might be more efficiant ways to do it.

Hopefully this is what you were looking for

Answer (score 0):

As Taco pointed out, you can call `Integer.toBinaryString(int)`, but if this is for an assignment or something where you should write the method yourself, here is what I would do.

I would write a method, that will constantly divide the number by 2, and store the remainders in a String. Something like this:

```
String binaryString = "";
int value = 100;
while(value > 0){
   int remainder = value % 2;
   value = value/2;
   binaryString = remainder + binaryString;
}
```

I tested this in a quick console run and it produced '1100100' which is correct.

**EDIT** I used this as a [reference](http://www.wikihow.com/Convert-from-Decimal-to-Binary).